# How do I show a loading gif after clicking submit, but undo it if validations aren't met

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

I have a few forms live.  My forms use jQuery validator for the front-end.  I have a method in place right now that switches out my submit button with a loading gif.  The issue is that when the validations aren't met the gif continues, not giving the user the chance to resubmit the form.  I've included some of my code below, any help as appreciated.

HTML

```
 <div id="subbuttonfirst">
            <button onclick="anothermethod.local.submit(this.form); ButtonClicked();" class="action submit btn btn-success" >Submit</button>
```

JS (Replacing function)

```
<script type="text/javascript">


function ButtonClicked()
{
   document.getElementById("subbuttonfirst").style.display = "none"; // to undisplay
   document.getElementById("loadbutton").style.display = ""; // to display
   return true;
}
var FirstLoading = true;
function RestoreSubmitButton()
{
   if( FirstLoading )
   {
      FirstLoading = false;
      return;
   }
   document.getElementById("subbottonfirst").style.display = ""; // to display
   document.getElementById("loadbutton").style.display = "none"; // to undisplay
}
// To disable restoring submit button, disable or delete next line.
document.onfocus = RestoreSubmitButton;
</script>
```

jQuery Validations:

```
 $('.form').validate({ // initialize plugin
   // ignore:":not(:visible)",      
   rules: {
    randomone: {  

      required: true, 
      number: true,

    }, 

    random: { 
      required: true,
      number: false,
    }, 

}
});
```

Comment: May be you can check form.valid() if its true or false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look to the options in the plugin documentation: http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate the `invalidHandler` option is what you are looking for.

You coul'd try something like this:

```
$('.form').validate({ // initialize plugin
    // ignore:":not(:visible)",      
       rules: {
        randomone: {  
          required: true, 
          number: true,
        }, 

        random: { 
          required: true,
          number: false,
        }
      },

      invalidHandler: function(event, validator) {
          RestoreSubmitButton();
      }
});
```

EDIT - A working example

The form:

```
<form class='form' action="?" method="post">
<input name="randomone" id="randomone" type="text" />
<input name="random" id="random" type="text"/>
<div id="subbuttonfirst">
     <button class="action submit btn btn-success" >Submit</button>
     <div class="loadbutton">
         loading    
     </div>
</div>
</form>
```

The js code

```
$('.form').validate({ // initialize plugin
   // ignore:":not(:visible)",      
   rules: {
      randomone: {  
          required: true, 
          number: true,
      }, 

      random: { 
          required: true,
          number: false,
      }
  }, 

  submitHandler: function(){
      $(".submit").hide();
      $(".loadbutton").show();
  }, 

  invalidHandler: function(){
      $(".submit").show();
      $(".loadbutton").hide();
  }

});
```

A working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9bqe65rm/)

Comment: would I need to change anything in the html, or my first method, or could I just call that inside of my validations?

Comment: I guess I just need to figure out what I need to change that first argument two because right now it is breaking my next button (this is a multipage form)

Comment: it coul'd work, but is better practice to avoid inline js in your html, so is better if you submit the form and fire the `ButtonClicked();` inside the plugin `submitHandler options` you can see a good example in the docs i linked before

Comment: if you give me 5 minutes and i can provide you fiddle

Comment: that sounds great, sorry on the late response, multiple projects.

Comment: For somereason this is breaking my application, I see it working perfectly in the fiddle, I've been playing around with it alot, and I think it may be due to some of my other functions in regards to submit button, I had two seperate methods being triggered by the onclick, could the other one I left be breaking it?

Comment: You should really try to avoid to use inline js code in your html, not a good practice, js should be separate from html. You can use the jquery.click handler instad of onclick, or create an handler in pure js. If the other method has to be triggered on the same submit you can execue it inside the `submitHandler` or inside the `invalidHandler` (or in both)

Answer (score 1):

Using [invalidHandler](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/) with a callback that replaces the gif with the button.